# UIButton custom button wont change font colour on select

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm using this code to create a UIButton, however when pressing the button the font doesn't change colour.

```
_gameSlider = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_gameSlider setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderBackgroundSticker"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(22, 16, 22, 16)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _gameSlider.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 70);
    newCnt = self.view.center;
    newCnt.y = newCnt.y + 120;
    _gameSlider.center = newCnt;
    [_gameSlider setTitle:@"PLAY" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_gameSlider.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:22]];
    [_gameSlider setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_gameSlider setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_gameSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_gameSlider];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your background color you want under forState:Highlighted.

While its being pressed it isn't in `UIControlStateNormal` it's `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

Comment: That doesn't even compile. Surely when it's pressed its in UIControlStateSelected?!

Comment: No, its control state highlighted while being pressed down, not selected. You know what i mean, add code under if its highlighted, that will fix your problem.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I only want it to change while being pressed down. The background changes but the title doesn't.

Comment: Then you put that under forState:Highlighted, highlighted is what it is while being pressed down.